# Class definition marked as not covered

Tags: c++, qt, code-coverage, catch-unit-test, codecov

I set up Codecov for a personal (open source) project in Qt. The project is still mostly a stub (barely a couple of classes, and I tried to achieve 100% coverage as of now. However, looking at the headers of these two classes in the Codecov report, one is seen as covered and the other is not, even if there are unit tests for both of them and they both pass.

[image: Attribute coverage fails]

[image: Character coverage passes]

I tested both of them in Catch2:

```
#include "../thirdparty/catch/catch.hpp"
#include "character/attributes/attribute.h"

#define TEST_ATTRIBUTE_NAME "test-attribute"
#define TEST_ATTRIBUTE_VALUE 1

TEST_CASE("Attributes")
{
  SECTION("should create new attribute correctly (name constructor)")
  {
    character::attribute sut(TEST_ATTRIBUTE_NAME);
    REQUIRE(QString(TEST_ATTRIBUTE_NAME) == QString(sut));
    REQUIRE(0 == int(sut));
  }

  SECTION("should create new attribute correctly (name and value constructor)")
  {
    character::attribute sut(TEST_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, TEST_ATTRIBUTE_VALUE);
    REQUIRE(QString(TEST_ATTRIBUTE_NAME) == QString(sut));
    REQUIRE(TEST_ATTRIBUTE_VALUE == int(sut));
  }
}
```

Following the DRY principle I won't paste the test code for `character::character` ;)

At first I was using a `using character::attribute` directive in the attributes test, so I removed it to see if the namespace was causing troubles. Also, I conformed the brackets model of `attribute` to match `character`, all to no avail.

This isn't a critical issue, but I'm curious as to what may be causing this behaviour and if / how it can be fixed. Also, I wonder if I should actually cut off the headers folder entirely from coverage checks, but I think it wouldn't be good practice.

Insights?

**Edit** Looking at the Codecov output on Travis, I found that there are three occurrences of `attribute.h`. The first one displays the following information:

```
File '.../attributes/attribute.h'
Lines executed:100.00% of 1
No branches
Calls executed:100.00% of 1
Creating '^#...#attributes#attribute.h.gcov'
```

While the other two occurrences display the following:

```
File '.../attributes/attribute.h'
Lines executed:0.00% of 1
No branches
Calls executed:0.00% of 1
Creating '^#...#attributes#attribute.h.gcov'
```

I suspect thus that the only instance that gets considered is the last one, which shows 0% executions as opposed to `character.h` which only appears once in the log.

Comment: Debug build? Optimized build?

Comment: Good idea, I'll try to disable optimisations and update the thread. Right now it's only `qmake test.pro`, so I guess it might build with the release configuration by default.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a proper coverage report, you need to run your build in debug mode. Optimized build will have code that has been removed.

`gcov`/`lcov` can only do so much with these missing bits, and that's why you don't see the code tagged as covered even if it was indeed tested.

Comment: Added `CONFIG+=debug` and `-O0` to the build process, and while Codecov now does show me an additional class that wasn't there before (and was never used in the tests) the issue persists. The additional class is (correctly) marked as non tested. I trust the issue may be close to this, but have no actual way to check. Suggestions on log lines or gcov outputs to look for?